# Compute y-value based on x-value and function - Python

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, range, coordinates

I'm currently trying to teach myself how to plot functions with matplotlib in Python, and I'm stuck on a rather simple task: **Given a function f(x) = 2x +3, plot the coordinates in matplotlib.**

I have solved this the hard way, through *manual* calculation, creating a list of both the x- and y-values for x-values from -2 to 3.

**The Hard Way**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(-2, 4)
y = [-1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

This works!

**However**, is there a way to quickly obtain the y-values, based on x-values (from -2 to 3) and the function?

```
f(x) = 2x+3
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `def f(x):return 2*x+3` would be a good start, have you learned about functions yet?

Comment: How about `y = [2*val+3 for val in x]`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way to plot your function within a certain range `[A,B]`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def graph(formula, x_range):
    x = np.array(x_range)
    y = formula(x)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()


def f(x):
    return 2 * x + 3

A, B = -10, 10
graph(f, range(A, B))
```

Comment: if you are not going to explain anything about your code you could at least put a few comments.

Answer (score 0):

The `lambda` function would be very useful in this situation. You can declare your function using `f = lambda x: 2*x + 3`. The `map` function would be a good way to obtain all of your `y` values in a simple way: `y = map(f, x)`.

Here is the documentation on `lambda` and `map`:

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Comment: in python 3 `map` returns a generator instead of a list so it can't be directly used as the y array, instead I'd recommend using list comprehension: `[f(i) for i in x]`

Comment: This is true. If you are using python 3, then list comprehension would be the best way.

Comment: Comprehension works in both versions but `map` only works in vs2, so in general I'd say comprehension is more reliable.  Since this question was not tagged with a specific version tag you kind of need to suggest options that would work for both.